# Unable to activate aws-sdk-v1-1.67.0, because json-2.1.0 conflicts with json (~> 1.4) (Gem::ConflictError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Does anyone know how to solve this ruby error?
I tried searching for answers, but not much information came up on google.
Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

```
    computer:adminsite abc$ ruby script/build.rb -a ~/Library/Android/sdk/ -t -v -p -f -c HJMKCT8H -s /Users/abc/code/cloudTv/OneMainstream/ -b /tmp/ -d amazon_fire_tv
Traceback (most recent call last):
    12: from script/build.rb:12:in `<main>'
    11: from /Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    10: from /Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     9: from /Users/abc/1ms-platform-master/adminsite/lib/build.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     7: from /Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     6: from /Users/abc/1ms-platform-master/adminsite/lib/amz/s3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
     4: from /Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
     3: from /Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:217:in `try_activate'
     2: from /Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:224:in `rescue in try_activate'
     1: from /Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1441:in `activate'
/Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2332:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate aws-sdk-v1-1.67.0, because json-2.1.0 conflicts with json (~> 1.4) (Gem::ConflictError)
computer:adminsite abc$
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no information about your project provided. I suppose that you are using a Rails/Capistrano/AWS (as I do) and this solved my problem:

Use this gem instead of https://github.com/fernandocarletti/capistrano-aws

this https://github.com/forward3d/cap-ec2

Comment: It's been awhile since I looked at this. I have no Ruby background, but was trying to setup a build machine in QA and it required a lot of Ruby setup. We put this on pause after several of us ran into this roadblock. Thanks for responding.